# Product Flat Data index exception: SQLSTATE[42S22] [While installing Magento 2.4.1 as well as 2.4.3 enterprise version] Re-indexing issue

Tags: indexing, installation, magento2, product, flat

After installing Magento 2.4.1 version(Enterprise version)on windows and After applying the di compile command and while applying re-indexing I am getting the following error even with the fresh Magento setup due to which I am facing the keep on uploading page issue while saving anything at the backend:-

> Product Flat Data index exception: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found:
> 1054 Unknown column 'row_id' in 'field list', query was: INSERT INTO
> `catalog_product_entity_tmp_indexer` (`row_id`, `entity_id`,
> `type_id`, `attribute_set_id`, `created_at`, `has_options`,
> `required_options`, `sku`, `updated_at`) SELECT `e`.`row_id`,
> `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`,
> `e`.`created_at`, `e`.`has_options`, `e`.`required_options`,
> `e`.`sku`, `e`.`updated_at` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` WHERE
> (e.created_in <= 1) AND (e.updated_in > 1)

Moreover, there is no table named `catalog_product_entity_tmp_indexer` in the database.